# How Do you Make a Website Suitable for people who suffer with Color Blindness?

Tags: html, css, color-blindness

I am just researching on how web designers make there website suitable for people who suffer with Color Blindess. I was wondering is the a way where you can create a css which can be enabled by user when they want to change the color scheme of the site to there suitability?

Can Anyone Help

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com would be better suited to answer this question.

Comment: Should be migrated to http://ux.stackexchange.com (which I can't pick in the *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network* option).

Comment: http://designshack.net/articles/accessibility/tips-for-designing-for-colorblind-users/

Comment: Can be done but beforehand you can avoid providing information _only_ with color: a complimentary way will provide information even if the user is color blind (stripes and borders on a map, text in red/green cells of a table, etc); See [WCAG Success Criteria Use of Color](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#visual-audio-contrast-without-color) and, linked from there, relevant [WCAG 2.0 Techniques](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/?showtechniques=141#qr-visual-audio-contrast-without-color)

Comment: From a statistical point of view, red/green color blindness concerns 10% of caucasian males (Europe, North America, etc) but it's far from being the single one... Also blind people obviously don't see colors at all!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems better-suited for ux.stackexchange.com